# How to calculate the confidence interval (using "binom.confint") for a vector in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the confidence interval around mean using
`binom.confint`.

My data is in percentage and looks like this:

```
data<-c(56.8, 34.9, 45.3, 52.3, 48.6, 51.5, 45.2,55.2,40.4,42.7)
and n=10
```

I have been looking at other R scripts, but most of them use the following syntax:

```
 library(binom)
 binom.confint(x, n, conf.level = 0.95) # here I think X represent each single data points NOT the whole vector (e.g. data).
```

Any idea on how I can proceed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you get an observed response rate of 56.8% from 10 samples...  It looks to me as if `biom.confint` requires it's first argument to be the number of successes from the number of trials given by its second, so `binom.confint(data/10, n, conf.level = 0.95)` might give you what you want.  It certainly appears to give *sensible* answers.

Answer (score 0):

The function `t.test()` which computes the Student *t*-test gives confidence interval:

```
> data<-c(56.8, 34.9, 45.3, 52.3, 48.6, 51.5, 45.2,55.2,40.4,42.7)
> t.test(data)

    One Sample t-test

data:  data
t = 21.687, df = 9, p-value = 4.44e-09
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 42.35727 52.22273
sample estimates:
mean of x 
    47.29
```